# setState() or markNeedsBuild() Called During Build Error while calling function in future builder

Tags: android, flutter, dart

Getting issue while calling the function in future builder. Basically i am doing speech to text. and the text i need also in different widget. so whenever the future<string> complete the speech to text purpose. it displayed on screen. but in that movement i want to call the function.

```
final Function(String) submit;

Future<String> transcript(String method) async {
    debugPrint(method);
    return app_services.transcriptFile(widget.audioRecorder.recordFilePath);
}
```

and this future builder

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return FutureBuilder<String>(
      future: transcript(widget.method),
      builder: (context, snapshot) {
        Widget? child;
        if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.done) {
          if (snapshot.hasError) {
            child = Text('Error: ${snapshot.error}');
          } else {
            final responseText = snapshot.data ?? "";
            child = Text(responseText);
            // calling function
            submit(responseText);
          }
        } else {
        return Container(
          child: child,
        );
      },
    );
  }
```

I tried to use InitState but it didnot work. i also tried to use

```
SchedulerBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((_) {
    submit(responseText);
});
```

but then code runs infinitly

Comment: "and the text i need also in different widget" is a cry for some state management solution.  I recommend Riverpod.